# Has a pro golfer ever worn a sports logo during a televised tournament?

Tags: golf, finances

Golfers on the pro tour will wear logos on their hats and clothes which undoubtedly yield them revenue in endorsement money.

Has a golfer ever worn a college or pro sports logo on tour?  Specifically during a notable season, like a deep playoff run?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In 2004, Ben Curtis [was endorsed](https://www.golfchannel.com/article/associated-press/curtis-wear-nfl-apparel/) by Reebok to wear NFL apparel. His wearing of NFL apparel did not correlate with a "notable season" or "deep playoff run," but rather, the city he was playing in that given week.

> Curtis will wear the logo of the NFL team associated with the city where the PGA Tour is playing.